# How can I convert an fbx animation into a sequance of obj files for every frame?

Tags: export, animation, modeling, blender

The game engine I'm using asks for each frame to be in its own .obj file, how can I convert an arbitraty fbx animation into that. If not possible, how can I create such sequence starting from a single obj file? I'm not yet using any software, just experimenting with downloaded assets

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE! Which game engine do you use? What is an fbx animation?

Comment: Hi!, I use Ursina engine mainly because I'm a Python dev, and by fbx animation I refer to (possibly wrongly) to the thing I download from for example mixamo after I add an animation to the figure, It also offers to download it as a .dae file

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Do you know there is a Blender Stack Exchange?  That's probably the best place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
In Blender(version of testing: 2.93) import the fbx animation file.

[image]

Now select, in object mode, only the object you want, and go to menu
Object>Animation>bake action.

[image]

Now File>Export>Obj.

[image]

On the Export dialog check animation.

[image]

Here are the obj's imported back to Blender:

[image]

I hope this helps you.